# Efficient way to write Pandas groupby codes by eliminating repetition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
    'City':['C 1','C 1','C 1','B 2','B 2','B 2','C 1','C 1','C 1'],
    'Date':['7/1/2020','7/2/2020','7/3/2020','7/1/2020','7/2/2020','7/3/2020','7/1/2020','7/2/2020','7/3/2020'],
    'Value':[46,90,23,84,89,98,31,84,41]
})
```

I need to create 2 averages

1. Firstly, both `Country` and `City` as the criteria
2. Secondly, Average for only the `Country`

In order to achieve this, we can easily write below codes

1. `df.groupby(['Country','City']).agg('mean')`

.

```
+---------+------+-------+
| Country | City | Value |
+---------+------+-------+
|       A |  B 2 | 90.33 |
|         +------+-------+
|         |  C 1 |    53 |
+---------+------+-------+
|       B |  C 1 |    52 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

2. `df.groupby(['Country']).agg('mean')`

.

```
    +---------+-------+
    | Country |       |
    +---------+-------+
    |       A | 71.67 |
    +---------+-------+
    |       B |    52 |
    +---------+-------+
```

The only change in the above 2 codes are the `groupby` criteria `City`. apart from that everything is same. so there's a clear repetition/duplication of codes. (specially when it comes to complex scenarios).

Now my question is, Is there any way that, we could write one code to incorporate both the scenarios at once. DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

what I've in my mind is something like below.

```
Choice = 'City'   `<<--Here I type either City or None or something based on the requirement. Eg: If None, the Below code will ignore that criteria.`
df.groupby(['Country',Choice]).agg('mean')
```

Is this possible? or what is the best way to write the above codes efficiently without repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish but.. why not just using a if?

```
columns=['Country']
if Choice:
    columns.append(Choice)
df.groupby(columns).agg('mean')
```

Comment: My Objective is to eliminate duplication of codes. your code does exactly what i want. Accepted and upvoted. Thanks.